# chrome dev tools: find which script fired JS event/error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

the chrome dev tool gives me a error. actually i'm trying to get an http ressource from an https webpage :

[image]

i don't know where these files are called to change the target. i guess we can know with the chrome dev tool but can't find how. i would like to know which file is firing the call, which line... (if i get only the filename, it's fine)

someone can help ?

Comment: click on the filename and line number on the right side of the error message. That is the code that generated the message you are seeing.

Comment: sometimes this isn't true. for example, here it tells index.166 but i don't have such js lines in index at that line. no call to this in the whole page. this is called somewhere else. and sometimes, it says "jquery" but jquery don't make call to such external specific URLs...

Comment: jQuery did make the call. And you code called jQuery. In those cases you can normally click on the arrow to the lest of the error message which should open up the call stack. That should show you each function, its filename and line number. Some times, with an event or timeout, etc. you may not see your code in the call stack. If this is the case and you can't figure out which code of yours caused this code to be called, then you might need to add a series of `console.log` calls. If you want to see the call stack of where you code is, then use `console.error` instead of `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue box in the picture below represents the link to the exact line that caused the error. The format is `filename:XX`, where `filename` is the name of the file where the script originated, and `XX` is the line of code within that file.

[image: origin of errors]

Click the link to see that line of code in the **Sources** panel. If the file is minified, [click the **Format** button](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format) to pretty-print it.